Number of partitions of (a,b) into k distinct parts which sum up to (a,b)
Problem set
This is somewhat a generalization of the famous partition of integer n into k parts.
Given two integers a,b I need to find the number of partitions into k distinct parts that sum up to (a,b). E.g if (a,b)=(4,6) and k=2 we have q(a,b,k)=7 since the following are partitions:

((1, 1) + (3, 5))

((1, 2) + (3, 4))

((1, 3) + (3, 3))

((1, 4) + (3, 2))

((1, 5) + (3, 1))

((2, 1) + (2, 5))

((2, 2) + (2, 4))


Notice that partition ((2, 3) + (2, 3)) is not taken into account since the parts are the same and each partition is counted once (meaning ((2, 2) + (2, 4)) and ((2, 4) + (2, 2)) are one and the same partition.
My solution
class Partition_2D_K_PARTS:
    def __init__(self, a, b, k) -> None:
        self.q_a_b_k = 0 # counts q(a,b,k)
        self.stack_partition = collections.deque() # represent a partition
        self.calculate_partitions_for_single(a, b, k)

    def calculate_partitions_for_single(self, c, d, k):
        if (k==1):
            if (c==0 or d==0):
                return 
            last_part = (c,d)
            second_to_last_part = (1, 0) if not self.stack_partition else self.stack_partition[-1]
            if (second_to_last_part < last_part):
                self.q_a_b_k += 1
                return 
            else:
                return 
        
        second_to_last_part = (1, 0) if not self.stack_partition else self.stack_partition[-1]
        for j in range(second_to_last_part[1] + 1, d+1):
            i = second_to_last_part[0]
            self.stack_partition.append((i, j))
            self.calculate_partitions_for_single(c-i, d-j, k-1)
            self.stack_partition.pop()
        for i in range(second_to_last_part[0] + 1, c+1):
            for j in range(1, d+1):
                self.stack_partition.append((i, j))
                self.calculate_partitions_for_single(c-i, d-j, k-1)
                self.stack_partition.pop()

My question is ...
As you can see my solution is using recursion (which is not very effective). I want to improve the runtime (convert it to iterative solution or something else.) but I don't quite sure how. Also, I don't want to use too much space since I want to use the function on very large numbers. I would like your help and thoughts on this problem.

Also on Stack Overflow: Number of partitions of (a,b) into k distinct parts which sum up to (a,b)

cited reference

Notice that partition ((2, 3) + (2, 3)) is not taken into account since the parts are the same and each partition is counted once

Sorry, I didn't get that at all.
Please cite some author who spells out these rules.
To break commutative symmetry we speak only of set membership, so we
prefer the pair spelling which comes lexically first, that's cool.
I would have expected to count (2, 3) + (2, 3) just once,
not twice and not zero.
I'm a little surprised that, given a, b inputs of (6, 4),
we  don't insist a <= b and make a call with sorted() inputs.
short name
            last_part = ...
            second_to_last_part = ...

Consider calling these ultimate_part and penultimate_part.
This isn't C, so in             if (c==0 or d==0):
there's no need for extra ( ) parens.
Similarly when comparing less than last_part.
Prefer a conditional increment of q_a_b_k
followed by unconditional early return.
Also, pep-8
calls Partition_2D_K_PARTS (with _ underscores) an abomination.
Spell out 2Dim or 2Dimension if you're looking for greater
separation between words.
Certainly all-caps PARTS doesn't belong in that name.
Public API
Please make this a _private helper:
    def _calculate_partitions_for_single( ... ):

It's not immediately obvious how that q counter
differs from taking len() of the list.
It would be helpful for the __init__ ctor to spell out
in a """docstring""" that we're evaluating for side effects
on the two public attributes.
Even better, consider offering def report(self): or similar
readout routine, which displays the found partitions
in nicely sorted order.
As written, a caller who has successfully called
p = Partition_2D_K_PARTS(6, 4, 2)
is kind of left wondering, "Ok, now what?"
variants and invariants
            second_to_last_part = (1, 0) if not self.stack_partition else self.stack_partition[-1]

It's clear you are trying to enforce some property on the
stack_partition attribute, something more involved
than "represent a partition".
It would be helpful if you spell it out, in an English
sentence and/or as an assert.
It helps folks to reason about what's happening here,
and to decide whether the
big-Oh
complexity of the task matches the complexity of the code.
We see that assignment twice.
Consider hoisting it out,
so it's the very first thing executed by this helper.
(Despite the fact that when c or d is zero it would
be a dead store.)
test suite
There isn't one.
In the Review Context you did point out that (6, 4, 2)
is an example of interest.
Without having motivated the problem,
that still leaves it unclear if we only want to
read out a count of 7 partitions,
or if the full list of partitions is truly of interest.
There may be an analytic formula which cheaply predicts
number of partitions, if that's all you need.
Consider instead producing a set of partitions.
Your automated test suite should include instances
of both trivially small and of larger problems.
performance measurements
There aren't any.
Yet this submission is about performance.
It contained no elapsed time measurements, and no
profiler
descriptions of hot spots.
Which leaves us to just guess that likely the nested loop
is of greatest interest.
It's unclear if "want to use the function on very large numbers"
means numbers up to a couple billion, numbers that fit
within 64 bits, or numbers that need python bigints
to represent them.
Numba could be a good fit if 64 bits suffices.
It doesn't look at all bad to me that we're recursing,
nor that we .append(), call, .pop().
Maybe we could avoid some of that work by tacking on
extra method parameters?
You're using a fast datastructure already,
but consider using a pre-allocated numpy
array
with a top index that you manually maintain.
Consider adding type annotations and using the
numba
JIT compiler.
If you had included literature citations,
we might be better able to see symmetries
that can be exploited in order to save doing busy work.
It seems like we should be able to copy-n-paste
results from sub-problems in order to speed things up.
Or perhaps refer to sub-problem solutions with a
symbolic reference, to avoid the work of copying.
There may be some way to work a helper having an
@lru_cache
decorator into all this.
Good luck in your quest for speed!
